# mysql connection lost when using two sqlalchemy connectors in the same thread

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

**Use case and background:**

I want to use `SELECT GET_LOCK` against a fixed replica, so all of my servers can see the same locks which are against a subset of my data, but distribute the load against mysql to multiple replicas, so that my servers can be working on different subsets of the data. Therefore I have `mysql_connector_locks` and `mysql_connector_data`.

Each of these `connector` objects is a wrapper around a sqlalchemy engine and sessionmaker. They each have

```
def get_mysql_session(self, isolation_level=None):
    if not self.session_maker:
        self.session_maker = sessionmaker()
        self.session_maker.configure(bind=self.engine)
    session = self.session_maker()
    if isolation_level is not None:
        session.connection(execution_options={'isolation_level': isolation_level.value})
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except Exception:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
```

Now, I have my code

```
for data_subset_id in partitioned_data:
    with mysql_connector_locks.get_mysql_session() as session_locks:
        try:
            with get_lock(session_locks, data_subset_id):
                with mysql_connector_data.get_mysql_session(
                    isolation_level=IsolationLevel.READ_UNCOMMITTED
                ) as session_data:
                    data = get_data(session_data, data_subset_id)
                    process_data(data)
        except LockNotAcquired:
            continue
```

where `get_lock` follows a standard recipe for acquiring a lock.

**What is going wrong:**

Each server goes through one iteration of the loop, acquires a lock for the second iteration, and errors with `MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')` on the `set transaction isolation level` query during the call to `mysql_connector_data.get_mysql_session`.

Again: it succeeds on acquiring a lock, getting a subset of data, releasing the lock, acquiring the next one, and then fails to get the data the second time.

**Other background**

Previously, I was using the same connector for both the lock and the data. This has worked for years with no issues. I'm trying to distribute load for `get_data`, and need to keep the locks common to all the servers. If I can't get this to work I'll switch to holding the locks in a common redis server but I prefer not to go this route if possible.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: A complete [mre] would be useful here.  The example code isn't runnable as-is.